# Cassandra startup fails when run in automation in vagrant/virtualbox on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cassandra, automation, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a vagrant vm running with cassandra, and everything works properly installing/setting up/starting the node when run locally by me and all other devs on my team.

I am trying to set up some automated testing jenkins jobs to use this vagrant deployment, and EVERYTIME i run the job on jenkins, the cassandra startup fails at the same point.

Any suggestions of what to look at?

vagrant 1.8.1
virtualbox 5.0.12
cassandra 2.1.12

```
==> anser: Starting cassandra0: 
==> anser: ...started.
==> anser: CompilerOracle: inline 
==> anser: org/apache/cassandra/db/AbstractNativeCell
==> anser: .
==> anser: compareTo
==> anser:  
==> anser: (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;)I
==> anser: 
==> anser: CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/composites/AbstractSimpleCellNameType.compareUnsigned (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/composites/Composite;)I
==> anser: CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
==> anser: CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
==> anser: CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
==> anser: CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
==> anser: CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
==> anser: CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
==> anser: CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
==> anser: CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
==> anser: Finished starting Apache Cassandra
==> anser: INFO  18:10:12 Hostname: anser
==> anser: INFO  18:10:13 Loading settings from file:/opt/apache-cassandra-2.1.12/conf/cassandra.yaml
==> anser: INFO  18:10:13 Node configuration:[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_rpc_address=192.168.33.34; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=cassandra0; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_node_timeout=false; disk_failure_policy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_compression=all; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; native_transport_port=9042; num_tokens=256; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=0.0.0.0; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=127.0.0.1}]}]; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
==> anser: Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

When I start up the VM on my local machine, it all works, and the output instead looks like

```
==> anser: INFO  11:47:22 Loading settings from file:/opt/apache-cassandra-2.1.12/conf/cassandra.yaml
==> anser: INFO  11:47:22 Node configuration:[authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_snapshot=true; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_rpc_address=192.168.33.34; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=cassandra0; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; cross_node_timeout=false; disk_failure_policy=stop; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; endpoint_snitch=SimpleSnitch; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; incremental_backups=false; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_compression=all; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=localhost; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; native_transport_port=9042; num_tokens=256; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=0.0.0.0; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_port=9160; rpc_server_type=sync; seed_provider=[{class_name=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider, parameters=[{seeds=127.0.0.1}]}]; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=true; storage_port=7000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
==> anser: INFO  11:47:22 DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
==> anser: INFO  11:47:22 Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 253MB
==> anser: INFO  11:47:22 Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 253MB
...
```

For the first time, I hit the same connection error while starting up my vagrant vm locally:

```
...
==> anser: INFO  15:33:25 Generated random tokens. tokens are [5068094952133832758, 2679523118211166036, 7061542167214604700, -5219888418907094150, 4804941159611263337, -4376755362226500910, -2339467726247596417, -3354301987075965037, -7733335365895491581, -3218196137132271011, -5972126150965914049, -5091966212567738519, -3882191021315178091, 1369997930610115015, 4032662741993252336, 6973804464569253192, -7863921685227041629, 2059083990352338132, -3985640375408386355, -429828593198594262, 3195812251615241303, 924448416748497774, 3868714962340157911, 6892444752914824972, -6050696714671927023, -303965947041560655, -3572317580829979157, 4882496837037825655, 6143231454247572590, -150078267522026853, 3313000336640597430, 3641586928942004870, -4931532468921034945, -7616662502278522780, -1158650423638355433, -1600189310387641543, 6812241145684483883, -7999194020457903369, -8987890332644393787, 1131713873540550136, -6442422838095513563, -3082197053449275885, 1424858409079592145, 4691775386443026760, -2671085640203933818, -8934367115857996164, -8363099700350463001, -5592441405538990148, 324888521827234211, 4848732007535504640, 2294387714210354248, 7870700382149543070, 4843204448822780209, -8302397481784890941, 3128706445924166948, 4703077392267541395, -7947000453147644246, 7073596445119748079, 8891833256689811255, -2543523205824907499, 5973151596968429046, 3275028356992465451, -9067083749372299534, 7497307184899407537, 1859849658279803322, -1066377454672761427, 5632847336330588514, -2416872034618097990, -4548687628865446573, -2689684037406633445, 7953580428092208050, 7167322475933166218, 6610501602634832681, 1298128819787650552, 4934888639572376111, -5804375337235098732, 3278927846080598353, -8581104399508435522, -2054735376315706452, -2851343176084866000, -5210334142478414366, -3971757251653581130, -2610135878906354642, 7692593837026574940, 2295485324366434621, 8405510678624964184, 7883129086689938777, 2547096978723509644, -7347407455114166110, -9033511299015949580, -7451814109309865759, 7669167386132399274, 6408254823180945010, 4537807111508222333, 6891695945754816341, 1741740249845687831, -7393404232705519767, 336327538507248878, -3952224804017043570, 7020538275541433438, -4741024370007814736, -7717579556441457130, 1639989990865810160, -1755162001565557891, 82200199707693891, 4382539928267082896, -6163707931964651763, 7575273494675661926, 4251495658353510224, -971030917140330689, 6813523918758371719, 421247106398192261, 5024407177691086822, 8520716418196481253, -4283876907861105785, -3137486262364667808, 725507115414963324, 1446873771923520175, -5345050679515216242, -2668271419213436376, 6643817382549322498, 8145822462122346902, 5611131326530556155, -5972758548697922058, 6583544701831248169, 105309022642636854, 6357308148487726750, 2303780869133390449, -3596727548104218415, 6248121024879758554, -4173003590235290672, -6481149746539708721, -3958196561829723687, 643096218529581756, -3469139731349837901, 8194396776789347322, -5133015170829896243, -4013395212529797405, -6528235358905889614, -2515548315419414476, 7385035482910338886, -917129760726407685, -8918319583863295770, -8349776351839877319, 5071512648418959950, -2038494881619526725, -9043069089436920328, 5899697784187861947, -9017057847236308466, -7930939469702955672, 6433439203398483462, -4444834513907660593, 613513072107116885, 1343393922123360673, 5294676815591437587, 4159152742167034516, -8922863682822464011, 3904709192434150175, 101191904500165189, 6858926593061260011, 8909727538410212713, -432549704270476371, -8799890237691141338, 935684678210325367, 5702446014222655634, 1653653296900596259, 2344965187488071762, -3458427354155422239, -3678832181617186732, -1964673341991687934, 5716168284360697699, 1794316499648441036, 6496771889509352478, 1679187751307347351, -1143339121155032096, -5427281620779761990, -4335760158193089485, -4293693262016663888, -1212931349054805070, 4058438299651338911, -4320141710450186709, 7042712347525619917, -6678518640241921514, 5634707580539961005, 2113821538697801700, 988651941103079572, 7950705359983673024, -9136273835168367337, 8244276733237309371, -5788819976164498376, -5652980257786886463, 1463209556561393827, -4540973916298925189, -1774938384912443965, -5228337141561284006, -4655014531980079333, -3139971530928749240, 7723864904215423069, 2671016496110414366, -2625377656624920728, 7716902478448493876, 30640835184414337, -6216482218184312068, 1554926156258597570, -7237040444837531069, 7804373934413720686, -1047899386733783926, -543776164426668142, 5106449657443367667, 6151546344120588460, 4032795592701984411, -2283312087249597914, 4899262916520733627, -8419142195154264544, 5697283562527396518, -1193532369126900689, 4746422596319322571, 4737711618513965127, -5129494447943281277, 532380223462508763, -3566436615209807464, -5691747047908301162, -6370265991691367777, -530590201241582682, 6269299690959593591, -7532244947434102499, -5520654521489521711, 6783360319482649580, -1090714056607386027, 648150464733519696, -3972603387877558998, 7250881356960202064, 4874049071753195014, -845194276015522270, -3451690332891566750, -5147413316264713106, 5039706248056511930, 7976698686553018374, -1413475412167157464, 6394102740286450138, -8201369736629552939, 3316156279562132403, -5548717243751270610, -384663260917930154, 5450500939801948971, 4002944274254405728, -5997902549780916569, 8955564437981136694, 8700185800147608064, 3659403192473814434, -3082117039443433473, -2247715909148865466, -6698246367893586125, 7918652856575530776, 5444776270343371794, -3225410820244931669]
==> anser: INFO  15:33:25 Create new Keyspace: KSMetaData{name=system_traces, strategyClass=SimpleStrategy, strategyOptions={replication_factor=2}, cfMetaData={sessions=org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@2695c2a0[cfId=c5e99f16-8677-3914-b17e-960613512345,ksName=system_traces,cfName=sessions,cfType=Standard,comparator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ColumnToCollectionType(706172616d6574657273:org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MapType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type))),comment=traced sessions,readRepairChance=0.0,dcLocalReadRepairChance=0.0,gcGraceSeconds=0,defaultValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType,keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType,minCompactionThreshold=4,maxCompactionThreshold=32,columnMetadata=[ColumnDefinition{name=session_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType, kind=PARTITION_KEY, componentIndex=null, indexName=null, indexType=null}, ColumnDefinition{name=coordinator, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.InetAddressType, kind=REGULAR, componentIndex=0, indexName=null, indexType=null}, ColumnDefinition{name=request, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, componentIndex=0, indexName=null, indexType=null}, ColumnDefinition{name=started_at, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType, kind=REGULAR, componentIndex=0, indexName=null, indexType=null}, ColumnDefinition{name=duration, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type, kind=REGULAR, componentIndex=0, indexName=null, indexType=null}, ColumnDefinition{name=parameters, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MapType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type), kind=REGULAR, componentIndex=0, indexName=null, indexType=null}],compactionStrategyClass=class org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy,compactionStrategyOptions={},compressionParameters={sstable_compression=org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor},bloomFilterFpChance=0.01,memtableFlushPeriod=3600000,caching={"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"},defaultTimeToLive=86400,minIndexInterval=128,maxIndexInterval=2048,speculativeRetry=99.0PERCENTILE,droppedColumns={},triggers=[],isDense=false], events=org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData@438ae8b2[cfId=8826e8e9-e16a-3728-8753-3bc1fc713c25,ksName=system_traces,cfName=events,cfType=Standard,comparator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type),comment=,readRepairChance=0.0,dcLocalReadRepairChance=0.0,gcGraceSeconds=0,defaultValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.BytesType,keyValidator=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType,minCompactionThreshold=4,maxCompactionThreshold=32,columnMetadata=[ColumnDefinition{name=activity, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, componentIndex=1, indexName=null, indexType=null}, ColumnDefinition{name=thread, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type, kind=REGULAR, componentIndex=1, indexName=null, indexType=null}, ColumnDefinition{name=session_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UUIDType, kind=PARTITION_KEY, componentIndex=null, indexName=null, indexType=null}, ColumnDefinition{name=event_id, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType, kind=CLUSTERING_COLUMN, componentIndex=0, indexName=null, indexType=null}, ColumnDefinition{name=source, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.InetAddressType, kind=REGULAR, componentIndex=1, indexName=null, indexType=null}, ColumnDefinition{name=source_elapsed, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type, kind=REGULAR, componentIndex=1, indexName=null, indexType=null}],compactionStrategyClass=class org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy,compactionStrategyOptions={},compressionParameters={sstable_compression=org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor},bloomFilterFpChance=0.01,memtableFlushPeriod=3600000,caching={"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"},defaultTimeToLive=86400,minIndexInterval=128,maxIndexInterval=2048,speculativeRetry=99.0PERCENTILE,droppedColumns={},triggers=[],isDense=false]}, durableWrites=true, userTypes=org.apache.cassandra.config.UTMetaData@457ef1dc}
==> anser: Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Comment: the versions of services are the same as on the jenkins slave.

Comment: Is that your tests that are trying to connect to Cassandra when you get the "Connection error"?

Comment: And are your tests (or whatever is trying to connect there) running on the same host as Cassandra?

Comment: no, the tests have not run yet; the error actually comes out of the cassandra startup logging.  so this is all happening on the same VM.

Comment: I updated the original to show the normal logging that comes after the spot that errors.

Comment: Any idea what that is trying to connect? That *looks* like it might be an error from cqlsh trying to connect to the node, but Cassandra itself doesn't start cqlsh when it starts up. Cassandra itself doesn't start any kind of client that would try to connect to the node when it starts up. Maybe you have something specified in your vagrant file?

Comment: Basically, I'm wondering if this could just be a timing issue. The first time you kick off a fresh install of a Cassandra node where it hasn't created any of the data files, etc. it's going to take some time (probably up to a minute or two) to initialize everything. It has to create those files, the system tables, try to discover other peers in the cluster, etc. The very last thing it does when it starts up is start listening for client connections. If you're trying to connect before that's finished (via `cqlsh` or something else) you would see an error like that.

Comment: Not sure what it is actually trying to connect.  I'll try digging thru the cassandra startup stuff to see if I can pinpoint it.  

As far as a timing issue... the strange thing is that this provisioning works everytime on most people's vagrant instances, it is only on the jenkins build slave box that it fails, and it fails consistently at the same place.  It is beyond my understanding how the host machine would affect the VM's internal workings though.

Comment: But to more clearly answer your question, I am not trying to connect via cqlsh or anything else at this point in the provisioning.  I've merely kicked off the cassandra start up and am letting that finish before moving on to running tests.  In a successful startup there's much  much more happening AFTER where this error appears (as u described, all the init of files on disk etc).

Comment: For the first time I hit the same connection error while running locally, but this time it was in a different point in startup (still during cassandra startup).  will update original post with the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I feel a little bit silly on this, but at the same time, I still don't fully understand the issue.

I merely upped a sleep after the cassandra init from 5s to 30s to give the process enough time to get started before continuing on with the rest of the vm provisioning.

This makes sense considering the jenkins slave is just running slower than my local laptop and so the cassandra startup just took that much longer.  What I still don't understand is what was trying to connect to cassandra.  I do have a script to use cqlsh after cassandra startup, but it echos a line to stdout, and that line is missing from the logs, so i am confident it wasn't that.  But long story short it works now and I'm going to move on!